# Pip freeze gives different output for different directories for conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have created a conda envoironment on my local machine.

When I use the pip freeze command in two different directories. I get a different list of packages installed.

```
 cd ~/home/WORK
 conda activate test-release
 pip freeze
```

Output:

```
labaster==0.7.12
altgraph==0.17
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-project==0.8.3
asn1crypto==1.0.1
astroid==2.3.1
astropy==3.2.2
.
.
.
zipp==0.6.0
```

However, when I try it in different dir:

```
cd ~/home/WORK
conda activate test-release
pip freeze


altgraph==0.17
bleach==3.1.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
decorator==4.4.1
docutils==0.15.2
idna==2.8
jeepney==0.4.2
keyring==21.0.0
networkx==2.3
numpy==1.18.1
onnx==1.6.0
```

Can anyone help me with this ? I checked the directory of env's and they seem to be the same.

Comment: Its both times  `cd ~/home/WORK`